# store Image Path In Database

Tags: magento-1.9, database

How to store Image Path In Database and retrieve from `frontend`

```
public function fanbookAction(){
        $img = ''.$this->getRequest()->getPost('img');
                if(isset($_FILES['img']['name'])) 
                {
                    try{
                        $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('img');
                        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png')); // Your Format Here
                        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
                        $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'FanBook'.DS;
                        $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['img']['name']);
                        $img =$path. $_FILES['img']['name'];

                        $collection = Mage::getModel('fanbook/fanbook');
                        $collection ->setData('img',$img);
                        $collection->save();
                         $this->_redirectReferer();
                    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Done');
                    }

                    catch(Exception $e) {

                    }


                }
    }
```

**Form.phtml**

```
<form id="Fanbook" action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('fanbook/index/fanbook') ?>" method="post"
      enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="hidden" value="AQGISNWgIVMWTUnC" name="form_key">

        <input id="img" type="file" name="img">
            <input id="button" type="submit" value="Upload me!" name="submit">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to show in `admin panel grid` then use. but you have get destination file because of same name already exist then uploader give new name to that file.

```
 $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('img');
 $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png')); 
 $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
 $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
 $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'FanBook'.DS;
 $destFile = $path.'/'.$_FILES['img']['name'];

 $filename = $uploader->getNewFileName($destFile);
 $uploader->save($path, $filename);
 $img ='FanBook/'.$filename;

  $collection = Mage::getModel('fanbook/fanbook');
  $collection ->setData('img',$img);
   $collection->save();
```

grid column

```
$this->addColumn('img', array( 'header' => Mage::helper('fanbook')->__('Image'), 'align' =>'left', 'index' => 'img',"renderer" =>"Companyname_Modulename_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_Image", ));
```

you renderder Image.php

```
class Companyname_Modulename_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_Image extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{

    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        $mediaurl=Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
        $value = $row->getImg();
         return '<img src="'.$mediaurl.DS.$value.'"  style="width:100px;height:200px;text-align:center;"/>'; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to show image not url in admin grid

Comment: this is not complete url this only image path after the media folder.

Comment: Yes How to get Image in admin grid it shows url only

Comment: paste your grid code then i will show you how to show image?

Comment: $this->addColumn('img', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('fanbook')->__('Image'),
            'align'     =>'left',
            'index'     => 'img',
        ));

Comment: add the solution for showing it grid

Comment: Call to undefined function getImg()

Comment: check now there was mistake...

Comment: Got it also you missed Extends keyword now it's working

Comment: In frontend same way or different

Comment: frontend simple use directly in html `<img src="'.$mediaurl.DS.$value.'"  />`

Comment: Can you please check this is possible http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112287/send-email-to-some-customers-in-magento

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you just store file name no need to store path

```
public function fanbookAction(){
        $img = ''.$this->getRequest()->getPost('img');
                if(isset($_FILES['img']['name'])) 
                {
                    try{
                        $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('img');
                        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png')); // Your Format Here
                        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
                        $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'FanBook'.DS;
                        $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['img']['name']);
                        $img = $_FILES['img']['name'];

                        $collection = Mage::getModel('fanbook/fanbook');
                        $collection ->setData('img',$img);
                        $collection->save();
                         $this->_redirectReferer();
                    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Done');
                    }

                    catch(Exception $e) {

                    }


                }
    }
```

You can retrieve image on frontend as below:

```
<?php
$mediaUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).DS.'FanBook'.DS;
$collection = Mage::getModel('fanbook/fanbook')->getCollection();
foreach($collection as $child){
  echo "<img src='"'.$mediaUrl.$child->getImg().'"' alt='' />";
}
?>
```

Hope it helpful to you.

Comment: I tried Name also Not Store above code also not saving

Comment: Didn't getting you can you please explain more

Answer (score 0):

**This code is for saving**

```
 if($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()){
    $model = Mage::getModel('your/module');
    try {

       if(isset($_FILES['img']['name'])  and (file_exists($_FILES['img']['tmp_name']))) {

        $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('img');

            $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png')); // or pdf or anything

         $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);

         $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
          $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . '/';

         $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['img']['name']);

         $data['slideshow_image'] =$_FILES['img']['name'];

        } 
    $model->setData($data);
    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData($data);

    try{
    $model->save();
    }
    catch(Exception $ex){
    die($ex->getMessage());
    }
```

**For retrieve**

```
<?php
$mediaUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).DS.'FanBook'.DS;
$collection = Mage::getModel('your/module')->getCollection();
foreach($collection as $child){
  echo "<img src='"'.$mediaUrl.$child->getImg().'"' alt='' />";
}
?>
```