# Send email to some customers in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, email

How to send mail to customer whenever Seller add new product.

**Note** : If Seller Upload 100 Product Customer will get only one mail not 100 mail how write **cron job** for this

```
public function newpostAction() {



        /**
         *  Initilize customer and seller group id
         */
        $customerGroupId = $sellerGroupId = $customerStatus = '';
        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
        $customerGroupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
        $sellerGroupId = Mage::helper('marketplace')->getGroupId();
        $customerStatus = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getCustomerstatus();
        if (!$this->_getSession()->isLoggedIn() && $customerGroupId != $sellerGroupId) {
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($this->__('You must have a Seller Account to access this page'));
            $this->_redirect('marketplace/seller/login');
            return;
        }
        /**
         *  Checking whether customer approved or not  
         */
        if ($customerStatus != 1) {
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($this->__('Admin Approval is required. Please wait until admin confirms your Seller Account'));
            $this->_redirect('marketplace/seller/login');
            return;
        }
        /**
         *  Initializing variables
         */
        $productNameTrim = $set = $setbase = $type = $store = $sellerId = '';
        /**
         *  Getting  product values       
         */
        $type = $this->getRequest()->getPost('type');
        /**
         *  Attribute set 
         */
        $set = $this->getRequest()->getPost('set');
       $setbase = $this->getRequest()->getPost('setbase');
        $store = $this->getRequest()->getPost('store');
        if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
            $sellerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId();
        }
        /**
         *  Getting group id
         */
        $groupId = Mage::helper('marketplace')->getGroupId();
        /**
         *  Getting product data from product array
         */
        $productData = $this->getRequest()->getPost('product');

        $silkType = $productData['silktype'];

        /**
         *  Getting product categories from category_ids array    
         */
        $categoryIds = $this->getRequest()->getPost('category_ids');
        if (!empty($productData['name']) && !empty($productData['description']) && isset($productData['price']) && isset($productData['stock_data']['qty']) && !empty($type)) {
            /**
             *  Initilize product weight
             */
            if ($type == 'simple') {
                if (!isset($productData['weight'])) {
                    $productData['weight'] = 0;
                }
            }
            /**
             *  Assing product short description     
             */
            if (!empty($productData['short_description'])) {
                $productData['short_description'] = $productData['short_description'];
            }
            /**
             *  Assign create at time
             */
            $createdAt = Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtDate();

            /**
             *  Getting instance for catalog product collection       
             */
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
            /**
             *  Initialize product sku 
             */         

            if(isset($productData['sku'])){
                $skuProductId = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->getIdBySku(trim($productData['sku']));        
            if(!empty($skuProductId)){
                /**
                 *  Error message redirect to create new product page
                 */
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($this->__('SKU Not Available'));
                $this->_redirect('marketplace/product/new/');
                return;
            }
            }           


            /**
             *  Initialize product attribute set id
             */
            if (!empty($set)) {
            $product->setAttributeSetId($set);
            }else{           
            $sDefaultAttributeSetId = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
                ->getEntityType(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY)
                ->getDefaultAttributeSetId();  
            $product->setAttributeSetId($sDefaultAttributeSetId);
            }    

            /**
             *  Initialize product type
             */
            if (isset($type)) {
                $product->setTypeId($type);
            }


            /**
             *  Initialize product categories
             */
            if (isset($categoryIds)) {
                $product->setCategoryIds($categoryIds);
            }
            $product->setSilktype($silkType);

            /**
             *  Storing product data's to all store view 
             */
            $product->setStoreId(0);

            /**
             *  Initialize product create at time
             */
            if (isset($createdAt)) {
                $product->setCreatedAt($createdAt);
            }
            /**
             *  Initialize seller id  
             */
            if (isset($sellerId)) {
                $product->setSellerId($sellerId);
            }

            /**
             *  Initialize group id  
             */
            if (isset($groupId)) {
                $product->setGroupId($groupId);
            }           

            /**
             * Set is assign product 
             */
            $product->setIsAssignProduct(0);

            $uploadsData = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();
            $filesDataArray = $uploadsData->getFileInfo();

            /**
             *  Checking whether image exist or not    
             */
            if (!empty($filesDataArray)) {
                foreach ($filesDataArray as $key => $value) {
                    /**
                     *  Initilize file name
                     */
                    $filename = $key;

                    if (substr($key, 0, 5) == 'image') {
                        if (isset($filesDataArray[$filename]['name']) && (file_exists($filesDataArray[$filename]['tmp_name']))) {
                            try {
                                $imagesPath[] = Mage::helper('marketplace/marketplace')->uploadImage($filename, $filesDataArray);
                            } catch (Exception $e) {
                                /**
                                 *  Display error message for images upload   
                                 */
                                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($this->__($e->getMessage()));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            /**
             *  Adding Product images       
             */
            if (!empty($imagesPath)) {
                $product->setMediaGallery(array('images' => array(), 'values' => array()));
                foreach ($imagesPath as $value) {
                    $product->addImageToMediaGallery($value, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false);
                }
            }


            /**
             *   Initialize dispatch event for product prepare  
             */
            Mage::dispatchEvent(
                    'catalog_product_prepare_save', array('product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest())
            );         

            /**
             *  Assign configurable product data
             */
            if ($type == 'configurable') {              
                $attributeIds = $this->getRequest()->getPost('attributes');
                $isInStock = 1;
                if(isset($productData['stock_data']['is_in_stock'])){
                    $isInStock = $productData['stock_data']['is_in_stock'];
                }            
                $productData['stock_data'] = array();               
                if(count($attributeIds) >= 1){
                    $attributeIds = array_unique($attributeIds);                
                    $product->getTypeInstance()->setUsedProductAttributeIds($attributeIds);                 
                    $configurableAttributesData = $product->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray();                  
                    $product->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);
                    $product->setConfigurableAttributesData($configurableAttributesData);
                    $product->setConfigurableProductsData(array());
                }
            }

            /**
             *  Adding data to product instanse
             */
            if (!empty($productData)) {
                $product->addData($productData);
            }
            /**
             *  Saving new product      
             */
            try {
                $product->save();

                if($type == 'configurable'){
                    $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item');
                    $stockItem->assignProduct($product);
                    $stockItem->setData('stock_id', 1);
                    if(isset($productData['stock_data']['qty'])){
                    $stockItem->setData('qty', $productData['stock_data']['qty']);
                    }else{
                        $stockItem->setData('qty', 0);
                    }
                    $stockItem->setData('use_config_min_qty', 1);
                    $stockItem->setData('use_config_backorders', 1);
                    $stockItem->setData('min_sale_qty', 1);
                    $stockItem->setData('use_config_min_sale_qty', 1);
                    $stockItem->setData('use_config_max_sale_qty', 1);
                    $stockItem->setData('is_in_stock', $isInStock);
                    $stockItem->setData('use_config_notify_stock_qty', 1);
                    $stockItem->setData('manage_stock', 1);
                    $stockItem->save();

                    //This section is what was required.
                    $stockStatus = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_status');
                    $stockStatus->assignProduct($product);
                    $stockStatus->saveProductStatus($product->getId(), 1);
                }

                $productId = $product->getId();

                /**
                 * Load the product
                 */
                $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
                /**
                 * Get all images
                 */
                $mediaGallery = $product->getMediaGallery();
                /**
                 * If there are images
                 */
                if (isset($mediaGallery['images']) && !empty($store)) {
                    /**
                     * Loop through the images
                     */
                    $increment = 0;
                    foreach ($mediaGallery['images'] as $image) {
                        /**
                         * Set the first image as the base image                       
                         */
                        if($increment == $setbase){                      
                        $product->setStoreId($store)
                                ->setImage($image['file'])
                                ->setSmallImage($image['file'])
                                ->setThumbnail($image['file']);

                            $product->save();
                        } 
                        $increment++;
                        /**
                         * Stop
                         */

                    }

                }

                /**
                 *   Initialize product options                            
                 */
                if (!empty($productData['options'])) {
                    $product->setProductOptions($productData['options']);
                    $product->setCanSaveCustomOptions(1);
                    $product->save();
                }

                /**
                 *  Checking whether image or not
                 */
                if (!empty($imagesPath)) {
                    foreach ($imagesPath as $deleteImage) {
                        /**
                         *  Checking whether image exist or not    
                         */
                        if (file_exists($deleteImage)) {
                            /**
                             *  Delete images from temporary folder      
                             */
                            unlink($deleteImage);
                        }
                    }
                }

                /**
                 *  Function for adding downloadable product sample and link data
                 */
                $downloadProductId = $product->getId();
                if ($type == 'downloadable' && isset($downloadProductId) && isset($store)) {
                    $this->addDownloadableProductData($downloadProductId, $store);
                }

                /**
                 *  Success message redirect to manage product page
                 */
                if (Mage::helper('marketplace')->getProductApproval() == 1) {
                    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess($this->__('Your product is added successfully'));


                    if (Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/product/addproductemailnotification') == 1) {
                        /**
                         *  Sending email for added new product
                         */
                        $templateId = (int) Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/product/addproductemailnotificationtemplate');
                        $adminEmailId = Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace/admin_email_id');
                        $toMailId = Mage::getStoreConfig("trans_email/ident_$adminEmailId/email");
                        $toName = Mage::getStoreConfig("trans_email/ident_$adminEmailId/name");

                        /**
                         *  Selecting template id
                         */
                        if ($templateId) {
                            $emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->load($templateId);
                        } else {
                            $emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
                                    ->loadDefault('marketplace_product_addproductemailnotificationtemplate');
                        }
                        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($sellerId);
                        $selleremail = $customer->getEmail();
                        $recipient = $toMailId;
                        $sellername = $customer->getName();
                        $productname = $product->getName();
                        $producturl = $product->getProductUrl();
                        $emailTemplate->setSenderName($sellername);
                        $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail($selleremail);
                        $emailTemplateVariables = (array('ownername' => $toName, 'sellername' => $sellername, 'selleremail' => $selleremail, 'productname' => $productname, 'producturl' => $producturl));
                        $emailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'));
                        $processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables);
                        $emailTemplate->send($recipient, $sellername, $emailTemplateVariables);
                    }
                } else {
                    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess($this->__('Your product is awaiting moderation'));

                    if (Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/product/addproductemailnotification') == 1) {
                        /**
                         *  Sending email for added new product
                         */
                        $templateId = (int) Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/product/addproductapprovalemailnotificationtemplate');
                        $adminEmailId = Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace/admin_email_id');
                        $toMailId = Mage::getStoreConfig("trans_email/ident_$adminEmailId/email");
                        $toName = Mage::getStoreConfig("trans_email/ident_$adminEmailId/name");

                        if ($templateId) {
                            $emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->load($templateId);
                        } else {
                            $emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
                                    ->loadDefault('marketplace_product_addproductapprovalemailnotificationtemplate');
                        }
                        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($sellerId);
                        $selleremail = $customer->getEmail();
                        $recipient = $toMailId;
                        $sellername = $customer->getName();
                        $productname = $product->getName();
                        $producturl = Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/catalog_product/edit', array('id' => $product->getId()));

                        $emailTemplate->setSenderName($sellername);
                        $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail($selleremail);
                        $emailTemplateVariables = (array('ownername' => $toName, 'sellername' => $sellername, 'selleremail' => $selleremail, 'productname' => $productname, 'producturl' => $producturl));
                        $emailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'));
                        $processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables);
                        $emailTemplate->send($recipient, $sellername, $emailTemplateVariables);
                    }
                }

                if($type == 'configurable'){                
                $this->_redirect('marketplace/product/configurable/',array('id'=>$productId,'set'=>$set));
                return;
                }                

                $this->_redirect('marketplace/product/manage/');
            } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                /**
                 *  Error message redirect to create new product page
                 */
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($this->__($e->getMessage()));          
                $this->_redirect('marketplace/product/create/');
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                /**
                 *  Error message redirect to create new product page
                 */
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($this->__($e->getMessage()));
                $this->_redirect('marketplace/product/create/');
            }
        } else {
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($this->__('Please enter all required fields'));
            if($type == 'configurable'){
                $this->_redirect('marketplace/product/selectattributes/',array('set'=>$set));
                return;
            }
            $this->_redirect('marketplace/product/new');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an overview on how I would achieve this:

- First, you will **need a new database table to store the customer that need to receive an email**. This `log` table must contain the following columns: `customer_name`, `customer_email`, `product_id`, `product_name`.
- Of course you will **need model,resource models and collections to be associated with that new table**.
- Then, **instead of sending an email as you currently do you will need to check whether or not the customer_email is already in this table. If it's not, you will need to add an entry to that table with the associated data**.

An example of such code could be:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('marketplace/log_collection')
    ->addFieldToFilter('customer_email',$customer->getEmail())
    ->addFieldToFilter('product_id',$product->getId());

if (!$collection->getSize()) {
    Mage::getModel('marketplace/log')
       ->setData(array(
                 'customer_email'=>$customer->getEmail(),
                 'customer_name'=>$customer->getName(),
                 'product_name'=>$product->getName(),
                 'product_id'=>$product->getId()
       )->save();
}
```

Then you **need a cron that will run overnight** (let's say at 1AM), in your `config.xml` you can do:

```
<crontab> 
    <jobs> 
        <marketplace_notify_customers>
            <schedule>0 1 * * *</schedule>
            <run>
                <model>marketplace/notifier::notifyCustomers</model>
            </run>
        </marketplace_notify_customers>
    </jobs> 
</crontab>
```

Finally in your `Model/Notifier.php` you need to do something like this:

```
<?php

class Vendor_Marketplace_Model_Notifier extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{

    public function notifyCustomers()
    {

         $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('marketplace/log_collection');
         if (!$collection->getSize())
             return;

         $arrayToNotify = array();

         foreach($collection as $log)
         {
              $arrayToNotify[$log->getCustomerEmail()][] = array($log->getCustomerName(),$log->getProductId(),$log->getProductName());
              $log->delete();
         }

        /**
         *  Sending email for added new product
         */
        $templateId = (int) Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/product/addproductemailnotificationtemplate');
        $adminEmailId = Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace/admin_email_id');
        $toMailId = Mage::getStoreConfig("trans_email/ident_$adminEmailId/email");
        $toName = Mage::getStoreConfig("trans_email/ident_$adminEmailId/name");

        /**
         *  Selecting template id
         */
        if ($templateId) {
            $emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->load($templateId);
        } else {
            $emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
                    ->loadDefault('marketplace_product_addproductemailnotificationtemplate');
        }

         foreach($arrayToNotify as $selleremail => $data)
         {
             $products = array();
             foreach($data as $logData)
             {
                 $products[] = array($logData['product_id'],$logData['product_name']);
                 $sellername = $logData['customer_name'];
             }

             $emailTemplate->setSenderName($sellername);
             $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail($selleremail);
             $emailTemplateVariables = (array('ownername' => $toName, 'sellername' => $sellername, 'selleremail' => $selleremail, 'products' => $products));
             $emailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'));
             $processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables);
             $emailTemplate->send($recipient, $sellername, $emailTemplateVariables);
         }
    }
}
```

So the **idea is to retrieve an array of products per customer, and to delete the corresponding log (so the customer won't get notified the next time the cron runs if the customer has already been notified for those products).**

The last thing you need to do is to **modify your email template to be able to process the array of products by using a layout such as**:

```
{{layout handle="marketplace_email_products" products=$products}}
```

Then in your frontend layout file you can add:

```
<marketplace_email_products>
    <block type="core/template" name="products" template="marketplace/email/products.phtml" />
</marketplace_email_products>
```

Finally in your frontend template `marketplace/email/products.phtml` you can do something like this:

```
<?php

$products = $this->getProducts();
foreach ($products as $product)
{
    echo $product['product_name'] . ' ' . $product['product_url'];
}
```

**Please note that this code will require modifications to match your requirements but I guess that will give you the overall idea on how to achieve it.**

Comment: Already I have some Customer in custom table it will work for auto email

Comment: @Kothari no you will need a different database table for sure.